# How to handle New transaction is not allowed because there are other threads running in the session for multiple calls or to save as list of Entities

Tags: c#, entity-framework

Hi I am using Entity Framework Code First, I have a collection of Entities that need to be saved, but I have my EF Repository created as below

```
    public T Create(T item)
    {
        try
        {
            if (ufb != null && ufb.CurrentUser != null)
            {
                SetValue("CreatedByUserId", item, ufb.CurrentUser.Id);
                SetValue("UpdatedByUserId", item, ufb.CurrentUser.Id);
            }

            SetValue("DateCreated", item, DateTime.Now);
            SetValue("DateUpdated", item, DateTime.Now);

            var newEntry = this.DbSet.Add(item);
            this.Context.Database.Log = message => LogHandler.LogInfo(1111, message);
            try
            {
                this.Context.SaveChanges();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                LogHandler.LogInfo(2501, ex.Message);
            }


            BuildMetaData(item, true, true);
            return newEntry;
        }
        catch (DbEntityValidationException dbEx)
        {
            // http://forums.asp.net/t/2014382.aspx?Validation+failed+for+one+or+more+entities+See+EntityValidationErrors+property+for+more+details+
            string msg = string.Empty;
            foreach (var validationErrors in dbEx.EntityValidationErrors)
            {
                foreach (var validationError in validationErrors.ValidationErrors)
                {
                    msg += validationError.PropertyName;
                    msg += "---";
                    msg += validationError.ErrorMessage;
                    msg += "||";
                }
            }
            throw new Exception("7777 CREATE EntityValidationErrors: " + msg);
        }
    }
```

My calling method is as below:

```
    public List<VehicleInfo> Create(List<VehicleInfo> vehicleInfos, string Entity, int EntityId)
    {
        bool vehicleExists = false; List<VehicleInfo> newVehicleInfos = null;
        if ((vehicleInfos != null) && (vehicleInfos.Count > 0))
        {
            newVehicleInfos = new List<VehicleInfo>();

            foreach (VehicleInfo vehicleInfo in vehicleInfos)
            {
                vehicleExists = false;
                if (vehicleInfo != null)
                {
                    vehicleExists = this.VehicleExists(vehicleInfo.VehicleId, Entity, EntityId);
                    vehicleInfo.Entity = Entity;
                    vehicleInfo.EntityId = EntityId;
                    VehicleInfo v = this.UnitOfWork.VehicleInfoRepository.Create(vehicleInfo);

                    newVehicleInfos.Add(v);
                }
            }
        }               

        return newVehicleInfos;
    }
```

Hence when I am calling repositories create method for multiple times, its throwing me the above error, any help or suggestion would be very helpful, please thank you.

```
    void BuildMetaDataNoThread(object item, bool active, bool isNew = false)
    {
        if (item.GetType() != typeof(JsonObject))
        {
            var dm = new DataAccessUnitOfWork(Constants.DefaultConnection);
            var qtype = item.GetType();

            if (qtype.BaseType.BaseType != null)
            {
                if ((isNew && qtype.BaseType.Name == typeof(ModelBase).Name) | qtype.BaseType.BaseType.Name == typeof(ModelBase).Name)
                {

                    Thread.Sleep(500);
                    //collect data
                    var element = (ModelBase)item;

                    element.BuildMetaData(DataRequestType.CurrentItem);
                    var records = ModelBase.MetaData;
                    ModelBase.MetaData = new List<ModelRecord> { };


                    if (records == null) return;
                    foreach (ModelRecord r in records)
                    {
                        if (r!=null)
                        {
                            var jsr = new JavaScriptSerializer();
                            //object meta = r;
                            object rdata = r.Data;
                            var type = rdata.GetType();
                            var token = type.BaseType.Name;
                            List<string> include = r.Include;

                            // Cycle-through clieanup of models to be encoded into Json Data.
                            // this helper eliminates infinate relations by including records specified
                            // by a list of strings
                            if (include.Where(x => x.Contains("CreatedByUser")).Count() == 0)
                                include.Add("CreatedByUser");
                            if (include.Where(x => x.Contains("UpdatedByUser")).Count() == 0)
                                include.Add("UpdatedByUser");
                            var data = ClassCloner.CollectData(rdata, include);
                            List<string> tags = ClassCloner.CollectTags(data);

                            string _tags = "";
                            tags.ForEach((xtm) =>
                            {
                                _tags += xtm + ',';
                            });

                            var json = jsr.Serialize(data);
                            int id = 0;

                            //get identity
                            foreach (var prop in type.GetProperties())
                            {
                                if (id == 0)
                                {
                                    foreach (var cp in prop.CustomAttributes)
                                    {
                                        if (cp.AttributeType.Name == "KeyAttribute")
                                        {
                                            var _id = ((Dictionary<string, object>)data)[prop.Name];
                                            id = (int)_id;
                                            break;
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                                else { break; }
                            }


                            var query = dm.JsonObjectRepository.GetAll();
                            var key = "_" + token;
                            var _data = (Dictionary<string, object>)data;
                            var ExistingMetaData = (from x in query where x.SourceKey == key && x.SourceId == id select x).FirstOrDefault();
                            if (ExistingMetaData != null)
                            {
                                if (_data.ContainsKey("DateUpdated")) ExistingMetaData.Date = (DateTime)_data["DateUpdated"];
                                ExistingMetaData.SourceData = data;
                                ExistingMetaData.Encode();
                                ExistingMetaData.Active = active;
                                ExistingMetaData.SearchTags = _tags;
                                dm.JsonObjectRepository.Update(ExistingMetaData);
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                var newData = new JsonObject
                                {
                                    Active = true,
                                    Date = (DateTime)_data["DateUpdated"],
                                    SourceData = data,
                                    SourceId = id,
                                    SourceKey = key,
                                    SearchTags = _tags,
                                    TargetKey = "GlobalSearchMetaData"
                                };
                                newData.Encode();
                                dm.JsonObjectRepository.Create(newData);
                            }
                        }                            
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    void BuildMetaData(object dataRecord, bool active, bool isNew)
    {
        new Thread((item) => { BuildMetaDataNoThread(item, active, isNew); }).Start(dataRecord);
    }
```

Comment: You shouldn't have repositories when using EF. You should have services and each service would create and use its own EF context. An EF context basically is a unit of work and each `DbSet` is a repository.

Comment: Hi @John its Code First, I don't know, it has been there since a long time, any help please

Comment: I reread your code and noticed reference to a unit of work so you're definitely doing it wrong. We used to create our own UoW and repositories in my office and we kept of doing so when we started using EF and we ran into issues too, for basically the same reason. Once we cut out the UoW and repositories and used the EF context directly in the services, those issues went away. Unfortunately, you're going to have to change some things about your architecture and cutting out the UoW altogether is the best option, as anything less than that will likely require putting out fires for some time.

Comment: Hi @John, at this moment of time I don't have that luxury to change everything and whole architecture of my Code, can you please suggest me anything I can do to fix the current problem. And another thing is, can you please provide me the code sample for your future fix as well, because I will do that after I fix this short release - please, you know how it works right

Comment: You should take the SaveChanges call out of your repository method and, in fact, all of your repository methods. The whole point of a unit of work is that it does all the work as a unit. It should have a Save method that you can call after all the work of creating the multiple entities is done and that should call SaveChanges. One save operation means no issues created by multiple save operations.

Comment: What does VehicleExists do, and why aren't you factoring in that result into your logic?

There is a *lot* of unnecessary "architecture" in your solution that honestly only serves to get in the way of using Entity Framework. Repository patterns can help abstract EF to aid in unit testing, but not like this pattern wrapping both the DbContext and a DbSet.

Comment: Its a temporary variable which checks if the Vehicle Exists for that Id, but its not important in create logic

Comment: If I try to create another Create method with the collection as parameter like this "public List<T> Create(List<T> items)", but it has the "BuildMetaData(item, true, true);" method after this.Context.SaveChanges();, can I call it before savechanges or how can I write it for collection call, I am placing the "BuildMetaData(item, true, true);" definition in the question, thank you please, any help would be helpful

Comment: Yeah more specific reason for VehicleExists variable is, once I complete the insert, I want to write the update as well, with VehicleExists I can use this variable for Update but for now I am stuck at the create itself - thank you so much for asking my friends